# Comparison operator for std::optional enum

Tags: c++, c++17, option-type, comparison-operators

According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_cmp), using a comparison operator on an `optional<T>` and `optional<U>` should work provided that the same operator is defined for the underlying types `T` and `U`.

I am trying out the following example with two enums defined in different namespaces (live code [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/coSlvH1DLLNjqWRI)) and can't figure out why it fails to compile:

```
#include <optional>

namespace n1
{
    enum class tag : unsigned {I,II,III};
}

namespace n2
{
    enum class tag : unsigned {I,II,III};
}

bool operator<(const n1::tag& t1, const n2::tag& t2)
{
    return static_cast<unsigned>(t1) < static_cast<unsigned>(t2);
}

int main()
{
    const std::optional<n1::tag> o1(n1::tag::I);
    const std::optional<n2::tag> o2(n2::tag::I);
    bool t = (o1 < o2);
}
```

My GCC-8.2.0 says that:

`invalid operands to binary expression ('const std::optional<n1::tag>' and 'const std::optional<n2::tag>')`

Any ideas? I've found out that moving each enum out of their namespaces, things work as expected (as [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4hWQBW4sfCVM14Ph)).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: just did, but you can see a more detailed report at the live code link I've provided.

Comment: On mobile so can't give a proper answer but look up about argument dependent lookup.

Comment: @linuxfever The question should be self contained.  Include all relevant details of the error in the question.  This makes the question of more use in the future, and someone searching for your error message can find this question.

Comment: Why are you comparing different enums?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<` operator must be in any of the associated namespaces of it parameters, i.e it must be in either namespace `n1` or `n2` but since `n2::tag` is not visible at the definition of `n1::tag` you need to place the operator in namespace `n2` or reopen the namespace `n1`.

defining the operator in namespace `n2`:

```
namespace n2
{
    enum class tag : unsigned {I,II,III};
    bool operator<(const n1::tag& t1, const n2::tag& t2)
    {
        return static_cast<unsigned>(t1) < static_cast<unsigned>(t2);
    }    
}
```

opening namespace `n1`:

```
...

namespace n2
{
    enum class tag : unsigned {I,II,III};
}
namespace n1 {
    bool operator<(const n1::tag& t1, const n2::tag& t2)
    {
        return static_cast<unsigned>(t1) < static_cast<unsigned>(t2);
    }        
}
```